# How to get values from derived classes by reflection in C# dynamically?

Tags: c#, reflection

I have this code with one base class and two derived classes :

```
public abstract class BaseClass
    {
        public BaseClass(string message)
        {
            //TODO
        }
        public abstract int ErrorCode { get;  }
        public abstract string ErrorName { get; }
    }

    public class Concrete1 : BaseClass
    {
        public Concrete1(int p1, string message) : base(message)
        {
            //TODO
        }

        public override int ErrorCode { get; } = 1022;
        public override string ErrorName { get; } = "NotFound";
    }
    public class Concrete2 : BaseClass
    {
        public Concrete2(int p1, int p2, string message) : base(message)
        {
            //TODO
        }

        public override int ErrorCode { get; } = 1023;
        public override string ErrorName { get; } = "NotSettle";
    }
```

Now I want to get all derived classes by using reflection and getting their parameter values including **ErrorCode** and **ErroName**. this is my code for getting all derived classes that is working:

```
 public static List<Type> GetAllDerivedTypes(Type type)
    {
        var assemblies = AppDomain.CurrentDomain.GetAssemblies();
        _listTypes = new List<Type>();
        foreach (var item in assemblies)
        {
            _listTypes.AddRange(item
                .GetTypes()
                .Where(t => t != type && type.IsAssignableFrom(t))
                .ToList());
        }

        return _listTypes;
    }
```

but for getting values my code doesn't work:

```
   var listOfDerived = GetAllDerivedTypes(typeof(ExceptionBase));
        var src = listOfDerived.First();//for instance

        Type[] emptyArgumentTypes = Type.EmptyTypes;
        var p = ((ObjectType)Activator.CreateInstance(src, true)).GetType().GetConstructor(emptyArgumentTypes);
```

How can I solve this problem?

Comment: I'm sorry, I can't quite follow what you ate trying to do in your second step. What do you mean by _"insert two parameter values including ErrorCode and ErroName into a dictionary"_? I don't understand what the code that you show is meant to accomplish (for this second goal)

Comment: @Flydog57  I want to get  parameter value(ErrorCode, ErrorName) from derived classess and put them all in a dictionary like dictionary<int, string>

Comment: Your setup makes what you're trying to accomplish very difficult; specifically, you need an *instance of a class* to reflectively get a field or property value; yet, you have *different constructors*, and *no default constructor* - so unless you maintain a mapping of your derived class to a factory method (or some method of instantiation), getting the values of `ErrorCode` and `ErrorName` properties of the derived classes is not going to be possible. Add a unified constructor (for instance, one that takes `string message`), so that all derived types can be instantiated in a polymorphic manner.

Comment: @CoolBots your explanation was great.

Answer (score 1):

`Activator.CreateInstance(src, true)` already creates an instance using default constructor.
If you have one default constructor for each derived classes.

So

```
var p = ((ObjectType)Activator.CreateInstance(src, true));
```

Should be enough.

But you don't have default constructors.

By other hand you can invoke other constructors using:

`src.GetType().GetConstructor(...)`

But you should have the same constructor prototype for all derived classes.